# Need to read value of array elements from one function inside another function using pointer

Tags: c

I am developing a code in which I need to read value from one function ("Read()") into another function ("compare") using pointer. Need to access values of "buffer" present in function "Read()". I have tried below approach, I am new with pointers implementation so not able to try much. "buffer" will have 9 elements which I have copied in "adata" in "Read()" function, need to have that data in "Compare" function.
Below is my code snippet:

```
    int16_t *Read (uint8_t *buffer, const uint16_t length)
    {
      static uint32_t totalBytes = 0;
      static uint32_t respNo = 0;
      int i;

      GPIO_ClearValue(PMAP_GPIO_PORT_DIR_RS485, PMAP_GPIO_PIN_DIR_RS485);             

      UartRxFlush(UARW_UART_INDEX_RS485); //this function needs to be executed after the GPIO_ClearValue in order to remove the "zero" value from the buffer
      respNo++;

      int counter = 0; // counts n. valid bytes put in slave response buffer[]
      do 
      {
        OSTimeDly(2);

        int8_t newBytesRcv = UartReceive(UARW_UART_INDEX_RS485,
                                         (uint8_t*)&(buffer[counter]), length-counter);
        totalBytes += newBytesRcv;
        counter = totalBytes;
      }
      while (counter < length);

      totalBytes = 0;
      printf("\n");
      printf("Byte received........");
      int16_t adata[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};  

      for (i=0; i<9;i++)
      {
       printf("%d  ",buffer[i]);
       adata[i] = buffer[i];
      } 
       printf("\n");

    }

    int16_t Compare(uint8_t * message, uint16_t len)
    {
      rs485_message_t rs485Msg;
      int StP15Vmsg[9] = {0x09,0x31,0x33,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x34};    
      int adata[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};  
      uint8_t buffer[9];
      const uint8_t length;
      for (int j=0; j<=9; j++)
      {
       adata[j] = *Read(buffer, j);
      }
if(compareArray(FWmsg,arduinodata,7)==0)
  {  

   char res;  
   uint8_t add, fwcommand, fwaction;
   uint16_t fwvalue;
   rs485_message_t rs485Msg; 
   proto485ComposeMsg(&rs485Msg, &add, &fwcommand, &fwaction, &fwvalue);
   res = GetABFWversion(&add, &fwcommand, &fwaction, &fwvalue); 
  }
     }
```

Please guide....

Thank you

Comment: In your `Compare` function you go out of bounds of the `adata` array.

Comment: you never `return` a value from `Read`

Comment: @sebastian Thank you for reply, What value should I return in "Read()" function, I have tried to return "adata" but it is giving me an error "Error[Pe120]: return value type ("int16_t *") does not match the function type ("int16_t")" even after trying to return "buffer"

Comment: you never return a value in _Compare_, you just set a *local* array never used after, and never do something near of a compare, why the name 'Compare' ? _Compare_ do not use its parameters. In _Read_ you set also the *local* array _adata_ for nothing

Comment: @bruno I have made changes based on your comments, but unable to get the values of "buffer" in "Compare()" function. it is showing garbage values.........

Comment: @user11265782 you missed a lot of things, sorry. You also have a lot of variables just declared or set for nothing (format, head ...), counter useless because always valuing totalBytes ... And it is not really possible to understand what you want to give you a better proposal. what are FWmsg and arduinodata you added ?

Comment: @bruno removed as suggested, actually I have kept that as was using in other part of code....... Can you guide me where I am going wrong with the above problem? Thank you

Comment: ok I will put in an answer all the strange things I see in your current version of the question

Comment: You should enable all warnings in your compiler. For GCC you could use options `-Wall -Wextra` and then read all warnings and take care of them. The compiler should tell you if you don't return anything.

Comment: @user11265782 I put my 'answer', you can read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : this is not *stricto sensu* an 'answer' but more a list of remarks

---

**About *Read***

the signature is

> ```
> int16_t *Read (uint8_t *buffer, const uint16_t length)
> ```

but the function never return a value, probably you want to return the number of read bytes, in that case

```
int16_t Read (uint8_t *buffer, const uint16_t length)
```

---

The static variable *respNo* is only incremented and never used, these two lines can be removed :

> ```
> static uint32_t respNo = 0;
> respNo++;
> ```

---

There is no reason to have *totalBytes* static because you reset its value to 0 before to print the buffer, so there is no historic from a call to the next. It must be *local*.

*counter* is useless because it always value *totalBytes*

---

*UartReceive* always success and never returns a value indicating an error ?

- if yes it is useless *Read* returns a value because it will always be *length*
- if no you have to take into account the error and probably *Read* have to return *totalBytes* valuing the number of read bytes

---

In

> ```
>  printf("\n");
>  printf("Byte received........");
>  int16_t adata[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30}; 
>
>  for (i=0; i<9;i++)
>  {
>   printf("%d  ",buffer[i]);
>   adata[i] = buffer[i];
>  } 
>   printf("\n");
> ```

- you loop from 1 to 9 rather than from 0 to 8 so you at least go out of *adata* and you do not print the value of the first byte in *buffer*
- you only set *adata* and you never use it, it can be removed.
- the format must be *%u* rather than *%d*

Probably the loop must be from 0 to `totalBytes - 1` to be compatible with the code above :

> ```
>  printf("\nByte received : ");
>
>  for (i=0; i<totalBytes;i++)
>  {
>   printf("%u ",buffer[i]);
>  } 
>  putchar('\n');
> ```

---

**About *Compare***

In

> ```
>  rs485_message_t rs485Msg;
>  int StP15Vmsg[9] = {0x09,0x31,0x33,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x34};    
>  int adata[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};  
>  uint8_t buffer[9];
>  const uint8_t length;
>  for (int j=0; j<=9; j++)
>  {
>   adata[j] = *Read(buffer, j);
>  }
> ```

*rs485Msg* and *StP15Vmsg* are useless, remove them

I do not understand why you call *Read* several times in the loop with a length incremented each time, so you will rewrite several times on the *buffer*. I do not understand too while you save the return value of *Read* (who do return a value currently)

Probably you want just that :

```
uint8_t buffer[9];
uint8_t length = Read(buffer, 9);
```

In

> ```
> if(compareArray(FWmsg,arduinodata,7)==0)
>  {     
>   char res;  
>   uint8_t add, fwcommand, fwaction;
>   uint16_t fwvalue;
>   rs485_message_t rs485Msg; 
>   proto485ComposeMsg(&rs485Msg, &add, &fwcommand, &fwaction, &fwvalue);
>   res = GetABFWversion(&add, &fwcommand, &fwaction, &fwvalue); 
>  }
> ```

I do not a link with the code above, and *res* is set but never used

---

*Compare* never does a comparison, why it is named *Compare* ?
It never returns a value, what value is it supposed to return ?